# Finding a directory with two specific file types and ignoring subdirectories

Tags: powershell

I have a task that involves looking for directories which contain two specific file types.  The parameters are that I accomplish this with PowerShell, I only copy one of the file types along with the directory structure above it, and ignore all subdirectories.  Here is what the directories look like...

```
├─ A
│  └─ A1
│     └─ A12
│        ├─ A123
│        │  ├─ working
│        │  └─ working_last
│        ├─ A123.txt
│        ├─ A123.log
│        └─ A123.properies
├─ B
│  └─ B1
│     └─ B12
│        ├─ B123
│        │  └─ working
│        │     └─ working_last
│        └─ B123.properies
└─ C
   └─ C1
      ├─ C1.txt
      └─ C1.log
```

So from this structure, I want to copy just the .log file (and the directory structure above it) only if the directory also contains a .txt file at the same level while ignoring all subdirectories.  I would like my copied output to look like this:

```
├─ A
│  └─ A1
│     └─ A12
│        └─ A123.log
└─ C
   └─ C1
      └─ C1.log
```

I have tried searching for the answer but I'm not sure I am entering the right search terms to find an answer.

---

This is as far as I got trying to just nail down the list specifically of directories with the criteria I have to meet.

```cs
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\" -Recurse -Exclude "working","working_last" |
    Where-Object { $_.Extension -match ".log" -and $_.Extension -match ".txt" }
```

Comment: Can you post your code that you've tried up to this point?

Comment: Get-ChildItem has -Include and -Exclude parameter, as well as a -Recurse switch.

Try this to see more options: Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full

Comment: This is as far as I got trying to just nail down the list specifically of directories with the criteria I have to meet.`Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\" -Recurse -Exclude "working","working_last" | Where-Object { $_.Extension -match ".log" -and $_.Extension -match ".txt" }`

Comment: You'll want to change your Where-Object query's regex operator to -or instead of -and, because no item will match both .log AND .txt

Comment: Are you really expecting to find files where `$_.Extension` is going to match both `.log` and `.txt`? Do you have some `SomeFile.txtlog` files or something?

Comment: This is where I get confused.  I need the script to only find directories that have both a .txt file AND a .log file at the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate the log files in your source folder tree, check if they're accompanied by a file with the same basename and the extension .txt, create the relative path in the destination folder, then copy the file.

```cs
$srcdir = 'E:\'
$dstdir = 'F:\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $srcdir -Filter '*.log' -Recurse | Where-Object {
    # Construct the path for the text file, then check if that file actually
    # exists.
    $txtfile = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.BaseName + '.txt')
    Test-Path -LiteralPath $txtfile
} | ForEach-Object {
    # At this point we have only log files that do have a matching .txt file.

    # Remove the source directory from the directory path of the file to get the
    # relative path. Prepend that with the destination folder to get the target
    # directory for the file.
    $relpath = $_.DirectoryName.Replace($srcdir, '')
    $abspath = Join-Path $dstdir $relpath

    # Create the directory (silently continues if the directory already exists).
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $abspath

    # Copy the file to the target folder.
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $abspath
}
```

Comment: Ansgar, thank you!  This was exactly what I was looking for and completed quickly.